# CodeBlocks : [highlight: No such directory found

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I have already read the other questions on the site and none of them matched with the issue I had.

I have already tried unistalling and then reinstalling codeblocks.

Please help.

Build Log :

mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions -g  -c S:\Coding\C++\aloo\main.cpp -o obj\Debug\main.o
mingw32-g++.exe  -o bin\Debug\aloo.exe obj\Debug\main.o

[highlight color=”yellow”]-lbgi -lgdi32 -lcomdlg32 -luuid -loleaut32 -lole32[/highlight]  "C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libbgi.a"

mingw32-g++.exe: error: [highlight: No such file or directory

mingw32-g++.exe: error: color=”yellow”]-lbgi: No such file or directory

mingw32-g++.exe: error: C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libbgi.a: No such file or directory

Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 4 second(s))

3 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 4 second(s))

Comment: It would be best to show what attempts you've made at solving this problem on your own, but since it looks like you haven't, here's a hint: the error is on this line: `[highlight color=”yellow”]-lbgi -lgdi32 -lcomdlg32 -luuid -loleaut32 -lole32[/highlight] "C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libbgi.a"`

Answer (score 5):

I have successfully solved the problem.

All I did was go to "Compiler Settings" ("Settings" -> "Compiler" -> Global compiler settings), and selected "Reset Defaults".

It solved the problem.

Thanks everyone for answering. :)

Answer (score 0):

Start by turning on full Compiler logging.

This is done by selecting the "Full command line" option Under menu "Settings" -> "Compiler" -> Global compiler settings -> [the compiler you use] -> "Other Setting" tab, "Compiler logging". In 12.11 and newer this is enabled by default.

This option will make Code::Blocks output the exact commands it uses to compile your code.

Things to remember:

- Look at the "Build Log" NOT the "Build Message" tab
- Do a re-build instead of build in order to get a full build log.
- You should review all the commands and their options;
- If you have compiled your app before, do a re-build (or clean before build) to see all compiling / linking steps;
- If you don't know what an option or a command does please read the documentation for the compiler/linker you're using;
- Look for missing commands;
- For every source file (.cpp; .c; .d; etc) in your project, you must have at least one command in the log. This command must produce an object file (file extension .o if using gcc/g++ and .obj if using Visual Studio);
- Every object file should be linked in the final executable, if not there are undefined symbols errors;
- Remember the file extension matters: *.c is compiled as C file, *.cpp is compiled as C++ file.
- If you have no luck, you can try to ask in the forum, but read first "[How do I report a compilation problem on the forums](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=FAQ-Compiling_%28general%29#Q:_How_do_I_report_a_compilation_problem_on_the_forums.3F)"

From [Code::Blocks FAQ](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=FAQ-Compiling_%28errors%29)