# CodeBlocks C++ program not running

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Few days back I downloaded CodeBlocks for C++.
I tried to run a HelloWorld program but it does not runs.
When I click on Build and Run nothing happens.
My compiler location is right i think (C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW)

Below the inteface is see this error message:-
**No such file or directory.**
Please Help!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZwL6.png)
`[enter code here][1]`

Comment: The problem is not finding the compiler, the problem is finding the library mentioned.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

It looks like you have something wrong in your compiler settings. Maybe look at this question: [CodeBlocks : [highlight: No such directory found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38232149/codeblocks-highlight-no-such-directory-found)

> All I did was go to "Compiler Settings" ("Settings" -> "Compiler" -> Global compiler settings), and selected "Reset Defaults".

Does that work for you?

Comment: If you don't have enough reputation to comment or to vote to close as a duplicate, then please don't post such comments as answers. Be patient until you have enough reputation.